How can I select suitable capacitance for an ESC?
Heads-up: I'm not an electrical engineering expert, so bear with me till the end :)
For a UAV project, I'm using a 4-in-1 ESC with 45A current rating. How can I select a suitable capacitor to work with the ESC? Also, there's been a voltage drop issue at the transient phase (take-off), so can I use a capacitor with high capacitance to compensate for the voltage drop, or is this irrelevant?
So, these are the main points I'm confused about:

How can I determine the suitable capacitor for my ESC?
How can I mitigate the voltage drop issue?


Who knows what the issue is and where. You need measurements what causes the voltage drop, where and why your ESC can't handle it. As an example, at 45 amps, to provide 45 amps for 1 second to only allow for 0.1V drop, you need 45F capacitance. That's 45 pieces of 1F capacitors. Best to try something else than adding capacitors.

@Justme One leg of the capacitor was found "burnt" after operation, so we concluded that something is wrong here.
Thanks for your answer btw!
